# Using pthread_create() after a fork() to sum two integers

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, fork, system-calls

I am working on a small assignment that uses a simple sum() function to add two integers in a child process and a parent process. Required libraries are included.

A thread is created in the parent process and is supposed to change the value of the sum after it is created. Creating the thread seems to work however the value does not change.

Output:

```
Using a fork(), the value of z in the child process is: 30
Using a fork(), the value of z in the parent process is: 0
Using a thread, the value of z is: 0
```

Code:

```
int x, y, z, err;

void *sum(){
    z=y+x;
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    pid_t child;
    pthread_t thread;

    // Initializing variables
    x=10, y=20, z=0;

    child=fork(); // child process

    if (child <0) // fork unsuccessful {
        printf("fork unsuccessful");
        exit(1); // check for creation error
    }

    if (child==0) { //child
        sum(); // sum x and y and store it in z
        printf("Using a fork(), the value of z in the child process is: %d\n", z);
    }
   
    if (child>0) {
        // in parent
        printf("waiting for child to complete....\n");
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Using a fork(), the value of z in the parent process is: %d\n", z); // value of z after the fork process won't change

        err = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, sum, NULL);
        if (err != 0) { // create thread, wait for it to complete, then print value of z                
            printf("main function: errno number is %d\n", errno);
            exit(1);
        }
        else {
            printf("Using a thread, the value of z is: %d\n", z); //value of z after passing to the thread will change
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `if (err != 0) { // create thread, wait for it to complete`. You don't actually have any code to wait for the thread to complete. Call `pthread_join`.

Answer (score 1):

> Using a fork(), the value of z in the child process is: 30

This is correct.

> Using a fork(), the value of z in the parent process is: 0.

The value of z is not getting computed in the parent process. So, it is printed 0. The address space of the parent and child processes are different. So z is 30 in the child process, but 0 in the parent process.

> Using a thread, the value of z is: 0

The main thread needs to wait for the sum thread to be over, using pthread_join, and then use the value of z.